# jquery datatable return 3 same respond with different encho each fire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, datatables

I had follow the below tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

but is weird that each time fire to server, it will return 3 same respond, same data but with different encho from server, is that normal behavior? but it will slow down table process ever just a few record, any idea?

**jquery**

```
var _bspaging = new bspaging();
            _bspaging.Render();
            self.$('#tblticket').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "sDom": '<"top"flp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
                "bSortable": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sAjaxSource": '/Home/Ticket/AjaxHandler',
                "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                    aoData.push({ "name": "sStatus", "value": status });
                },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Status" },
                    { "sTitle": "Ticket Date", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { "sTitle": "Ticket No.", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { "sTitle": "Title", "sWidth": "30%" },
                    { "sTitle": "Category", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { "sTitle": "Item", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { "sTitle": "Created By", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    { "sTitle": "Current", "sWidth": "10%" },
                    {
                        "sName": "ID",
                        "sDefaultContent": "",
                        "sWidth": "10%",
                        "fnRender": function (obj) {
                            if (status == "New") {
                                return "<a class='btn btn-large'><i class=\"icon icon-pencil\"></i> Edit</a>";
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ]
            })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I guess i'm wrong, I found the culprit that cause my jquery datatable return multiple response from server, instead of "bprocessing", I figure out that the RowGrouping plugin caused my datatable to return multiple respond from the server